$|z^2+z+1|=1$ in Argand plane
Consider the curve $|z^2+z+1|=1$ in Argand plane, this question was asked in IIT JEE (2020) wherein one can prove that $|z+1/2|\ge 1/2$ and $|z|< 2$ and the points $z=0,-1, 
z=z'=(-1+ i\sqrt{7})/2,\bar{z}'$  can be checked to fall on the curve. The actual figure of the curve indicates that $$|z|_{max}=|z'|=\sqrt{2}\cdots (*)$$

The question is: How to get $(*)$ analytically by hand?

From the triangle inequality alone, we've got $\frac{1}{2}\leq |z+\frac{1}{2}|\leq \frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$. Is this any good?

Yes, true but there needs to be a direct method to get $|z|\le √2$.

Besides using the triangle inequality, transforming $|z^2+z+1|=1$ into the form $f(x,y)=0$ is the next reasonable step for me, and if I've done the calculations correctly, $f(x,y)=0$ would turn out biquadratic in $y$.

I don't think that this is correct. It is true that $|z^2+z+1|=1$ and $|z|=\sqrt 2$ intersect at $z'$, but not tangential.

Claim:$\;$For $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z^2+z+1|=1$, we have
$$
|z|_{max}
=
\frac
{\sqrt{9+6\sqrt{3}}}
{3}
$$
which exceeds $\sqrt{2}$.

Proof:

Fix $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z^2+z+1|=1$, and let $r=|z|$.

Write $z=x+yi$.

Then from
$$
|z^2+z+1|=1
$$
we get
$$
(z^2+z+1)(\bar{z}^2+\bar{z}+1)=1
$$
which, after expansion, yields
$$
y^4+y^2(2x^2+2x-1)+(x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x)=0
$$
Then, replacing $y^2$ by $r^2-x^2$, we get
$$
4x^2+(2r^2+2)x+(r^4-r^2)=0
$$
which yields
$$
x
=
\frac
{-r^2-1\pm\sqrt{1+6r^2-3r^4}}
{4}
$$
hence
\begin{align*}
&
1+6r^2-3r^4\ge 0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
3(r^2-1)^2\le 4
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
r^2\le\frac{3+2\sqrt{3}}{3}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
r
\le
\frac
{\sqrt{9+6\sqrt{3}}}
{3}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
It remains to show that
$$
r
=
\frac
{\sqrt{9+6\sqrt{3}}}
{3}
$$
is actually realizable.

To this end, we assume
$$
r
=
\frac
{\sqrt{9+6\sqrt{3}}}
{3}
$$
and solve for a corresponding value of $z$.

Note that
\begin{align*}
&
r
=
\frac
{\sqrt{9+6\sqrt{3}}}
{3}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
r^2
=
\frac{3+2\sqrt{3}}{3}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
1+6r^2-3r^4=0
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence from
$$
x
=
\frac
{-r^2-1\pm\sqrt{1+6r^2-3r^4}}
{4}
$$
we get
$$
x
=
-\frac{r^2+1}{4}
=
-\frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{6}
$$
and then
$$
y^2
=
r^2-x^2
=
\frac{4+3\sqrt{3}}{6}
$$
which yields
$$
y
=
\pm\frac
{\sqrt{24+18\sqrt{3}}}{6}
$$
and then, letting $z=x+yi$ using the above values of $x,y$, one can directly verify that
$$
(z^2+z+1)(\bar{z}^2+\bar{z}+1)=1
$$
hence
$$
|z^2+z+1|=1
$$
which completes the proof.

Wonderful work +1. But why someone has downvoted my interesting question?
